# Convert a list into a nested named vector with the same length in R

Tags: r

Suppose for the list `x`

```r
x <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5))
```

I want to get back a named vector with the same length that looks like

```
c(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(4, 5))
```

My first thoughts use a for loop

```r
  out <- vector(typeof(x), length(x))
  x_names <- names(x)
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    out[i] <- x[[i]]
  }
  
  names(out) <- c(x_names)
```

Is there a way to do this without a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

How about using `do.call()` with `c()`?

```
do.call(c,x)
```

or

```
unlist(x)
```

Output

```
a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 
 1  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: or `unlist(x)` as well

Comment: yep, that works too @SymbolixAU  i wasn't sure what the OP wanted.  The desired output matches my solution, but it is not a "nested vector of length 2"..

Answer (score 0):

- Just use

```
lapply(1:length(x) , \(i) unlist(x[i]))

#> [[1]]
#> a1 a2 a3 
#>  1  2  3 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> b1 b2 
#>  4  5
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I'll need a nested vector with length 2, `unlist` flattens the list.

Comment: What about the above update ?

Comment: @Qiushi you cannot have a nested vector in R. with length 2, you need a list not a vector

Comment: your unlist answer was correct. You should revert back to it

Comment: @Qiushi The length of the output you provided is 5 and not 2